# Lightbox moves image to bottom right corner

Tags: javascript, css, image, image-gallery

I'm writing a lightbox image gallery and struggling with the correct image positioning.

When clicking on an image, the lightbox appears. It's a completely new object generated with JS. By setting the margins, I move it to the screen middle (with z-index).

But these actions are performed before the image got time for loading. So JS doesn't have the required information `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` and uses `0` instead. This effects that the top left image corner (which is before loading the same as the other corners as well) is in the middle of the screen.
When the image starts loading, it will be extended to the bottom right.

How do I position the image correctly on the screen?

PS: No connection to the lightbox/lightbox2 library.

PPS: relevant code:

JS:

```
function lightbox(res, dsc) {
    // lbimg: Lightbox-Image
    var lbimg = document.createElement("img");
    lbimg.src = res;
    lbimg.id = "lbimg";
    document.body.insertBefore(lbimg, document.body.firstChild);
    lbimg.style.marginTop = "-" + Math.floor(lbimg.clientHeight/2.) + "px";
    lbimg.style.marginLeft = "-" + Math.floor(lbimg.clientWidth/2.) + "px";
}
```

CSS:

```
#lbimg {
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    z-index : 10;
}
```

HTML (only miniature images are displayed):

```
<div class="list">
    <div><a onclick="lightbox('image.JPG', ''); "><img class="mini" src="image.JPG_MINI.jpg" /></a></div>
    <!--other images are defined analogous-->
</div>
```

Comment: whre is your html code?

Comment: I've added the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function lightbox(res, dsc) {
    var lbimg = document.createElement("img");
    lbimg.id = "lbimg";
    lbimg.onload = function() {
        document.body.insertBefore(lbimg, document.body.firstChild);
        lbimg.style.marginTop = "-" + Math.floor(lbimg.clientHeight/2) + "px";
        lbimg.style.marginLeft = "-" + Math.floor(lbimg.clientWidth/2) + "px";
    };
    lbimg.src = res;
}
```

You have to wrap both the DOM insertion and style setting in a load handler (if you wrap only style changes, you will see element "shifting" after insertion). Also set your src **after** binding the load handler, otherwise it's possible Internet Explorer will miss the handler (when loading images from cache).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your margin calculations inside an onload call:

```
lbimg.onload = function () {
    lbimg.style.marginTop = "-" + Math.floor(lbimg.clientHeight/2.) + "px";
    lbimg.style.marginLeft = "-" + Math.floor(lbimg.clientWidth/2.) + "px";
};
```

This will ensure that the height and width are available to the JS in order that the margins can be calculated correctly.

Comment: the onload function gets triggerd AFTER the image finished loading, so until it finished loading, the problem stays.

Comment: Well yes, that is the purpose of the ONLOAD function i.e. once the image has loaded do this. If you don't want to see the image moving around the screen you could try sending it to the back with a `z-index: -1`, and changing it back to `z-index: 10` once the margins have been set. Or you could try setting `opacity: 0` and then after the margins have been set `opacity:1`.